# Setting border property in excel using c# is not working in case of multiple excel file

Tags: c#

I am designing a small program using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library in c#. My program read the excel files(whose names are 1.xlss,2.xlsx and so on) and make a new excel file and then copy the data of all excel files into new excel files with one line gap. I also set the certain property like border,font,backgroundcolor etc of the cells.

Everything is fine for first excel file(1.xls) but in case of 2nd,3rd and so on, It's not setting the border property of the cells.Here is my code

```
// data member initialization for reading the sheet
        Excel.Application app;
        Excel.Workbook workbook;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        // data member initialization for writing sheet
        Excel.Application finalApp;
        Excel.Workbook finalWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet finalWorkSheet;

        String path = this.textBox1.Text;
        String numberOfFiles = (String)this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        int count = 1;
        int row = 1, col = 1;
        try
        {
            // Object creation for the final sheet
            finalApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            finalApp.Visible = true;
            finalWorkBook = finalApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
            finalWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)finalWorkBook.Sheets[1];


            // opening a excel file
            app = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            Excel.Borders b=null;
            Excel.Borders fb = null;
            try
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < Int32.Parse(numberOfFiles); k++)
                {
                    fullPath = @path + @"\" + count + ".xlsx";
                    workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(fullPath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value
                        , Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                        Missing.Value);
                    worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
                    range = worksheet.UsedRange;
                    int cnum1 = range.Columns.Count;
                    int rnum1 = range.Rows.Count;
                    int i, j;
                    for (i = 1; i <= rnum1; i++)
                    {
                        for (j = 1; j <= cnum1; j++)
                        {
                            if ((range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
                            {
                                string value1 = (range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                                finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] = value1;
                                b= (Excel.Borders)(range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Borders;
                                //MessageBox.Show(b.Weight.ToString());
                                fb=(finalWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Borders;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight= b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Weight = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Weight;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight;

                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle;
                                //fb.Color = b.Color;
                                //(finalWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).BorderAround(b.LineStyle,(Excel.XlBorderWeight)b.Weight,
                                //(Excel.XlColorIndex)b.ColorIndex,b.Color);
                            } 
                            (finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Interior.Color = (range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Interior.Color;
                            (finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Font.Color = (range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Font.Color;
                            col++;
                        }
                        row++;
                        col = 1;
                    }
                    //finalWorkBook.SaveAs("hello.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel4Workbook, Missing.Value,
                    //Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    //Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

                    workbook.Close(false, false, Missing.Value);
                    count++;
                    row++;
                    col = 1;
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error while opening the file "+fullPath);
            }
            //finalWorkBook.Close(true,false,Missing.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Some Error has occurred.Please check the path Correctly
            whether it's correct or not");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fb=(finalWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Borders;
```

Should be

```
fb=(finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Borders;
```